# Labeling Figure from String List

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following:

```
Mode = ["dense", "Iso", "hole"]
label = 400.
```

what I would like to do is when saving a figure I would like to name it:

```
savefig('Charlie_Mode= %_label=%.1f.png'%(Mode, Label)
```

So obviousely I am able to do the floats but not the mode thing any help??
the final result should look like:

```
Charlie_Mode="dense"_label_400.0.png
```

Comment: Where does `"Iso"` and `"hole"` go?

Comment: looks like you want only first element, why not choose `Mode[0]`?

Comment: Do you really want the quotes around `dense`, as in `Charlie_Mode="dense"_label_400.0.png` instead of `Charlie_Mode=dense_label_400.0.png`?

Comment: because this thing runs into a loop so for every Mode I need to Save a figure. even if I only want to label with Mode[0] I am not really sure how to do that

Comment: @ShawnChin does it make a difference?

Comment: Can you edit the question tags? I guess this is about matplotlib...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
'Charlie_Mode= %_label=%.1f.png'%(Mode, Label)
```

You should try:

```
'Charlie_Mode= %s_label=%.1f.png' % (Mode, Label)
```

Your first `%` is missing a `s` (for string).

Of course, it will still fail if you don't choose a specific element of your list `Mode`, like `Mode[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Also try using format so (from Pierre's answer)

```
savefig('Charlie_Mode= %_label=%.1f.png'%(Mode, Label))
```

becomes

```
savefig('Charlie_Mode={0}_label={1:.1f}.png'.format(Mode, Label))
```

Since I learnt about format I dropped % like a stone as it's so much cleaner. You may have some formatting requirements that `%s` and `%d` might make simpler however.

Note that the `format` method was introduced in Python 2.6 and will not work with older versions.